# awk Can not Select Column with empty value

Tags: awk, azure-devops

i am trying to select a column with its missing value
here is my input file separated by tab

```
1   2   3
4       5
    6   
7   8   
        9
```

i am trying to select the first column in which output will look like

```
 1
 4
   
 7
```

and the length of my column would be 5 in this case
I have tried
 `awk '$1!=""{print $1}' ./demo.txt`
but it returns

```
1
4
6
7
9
```

can anybody help with this I am new in AWK

Comment: Please edit your question to show the output of `awk '{gsub(/\t/,"t"); gsub(/ /,"b"); gsub(/\r/,"r"); print $0 "$"}' ./demo.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cut`:

```
$ cut -f 1 file   # the default delimiter is a tab
```

Or with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/[[:blank:]].*$//' file
```

Or awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/[[:blank:]].*$/,"")}1' file
```

Or:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $1}' file
```

All those print the first column and all five lines (blank or not)

Prints:

```
1
4

7
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell `awk` to use a tab (`\t`) as the input field delimiter (`-F`):

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{ print $1 }' demo.txt
1
4 
  
7
```

If you want to print multiple columns, maintaining the same delimiter for output, another approach using the `FS` and `OFS` variables:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } { print $1,$3 }' demo.txt
1       3
4       5

7
        9
```

Comment: it print all the value with others column

Comment: if it's printing all columns then your file is not tab delimited (as stated in the description)

Comment: i check it several time its tab seperated

Comment: did you use `print` or `print $1`? if you used `print $1`, consider updating the question with the output from `od -c demo.txt` ... this will let us see printable and non-printable characters in the file

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` something like:

```
sed 's/^\([^[:blank:]]*\).*/\1/' demo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`FIELDWIDTHS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fixed-width-data.html) in gnu-awk you can do this for fixed width separated data:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = "4 4 *"} {print $1}' file

1
4

7
```

**For demo purpose:**

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = "4 4 *"} {print NR ":", $1}' file

1: 1
2: 4
3:
4: 7
5:
```

Answer (score 0):

if they're all single digits in 1st column :

```
echo \
'1   2   3
 4       5
     6
 7   8
         9' |
```

> ```
> mawk NF=1 FS=
> ```

```
gcat -n
     1  1
     2  4
     3   
     4  7
     5
```

that's literally all you need. To play it safe, then do

> ```
> nawk NF=1 FS='[[:space:]]'  # overly-verbose so-called
>                             # "proper" posix form
> ```

> ```
> gawk NF=1 FS='[ \t]'        # suffices unless the input
>                             # happens to have uncommon bytes
>                             # like \013 \v or \014 \f
> ```

or a very fringe way of fudging `NF` :

> ```
> mawk 'NF ^= FS="[ \t]"'
> ```